# cpan error: Unable to get Terminal Size. The Win32 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo call didn't work

Tags: perl, cmd, cpan, activeperl

ActiveState Perl - 5.26 on Windows 10 - 64 bit.

When I am trying to launch cpan from CMD - I see the following error:

```
C:\Users\orenm>cpan
Unable to get Terminal Size. The Win32 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo call didn't work. The COLUMNS and LINES environment variables didn't work. at C:\Perl64\lib/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm line 410.
```

Why does it happen? 
What shall I do with it?

Comment: This is just a warning. You can ignore it. Alternatively, consider setting the `COLUMNS` and `LINES` environment variables to the size of your terminal.

Comment: Also, maybe you are launching Perl in a fancy console emulator and not the raw `cmd.exe` as suggested by [this](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=24598)

Comment: Just an idea, try running `set TERM=dumb` before you run `cpan` ([related thread](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1214933)).

Comment: The `set TERM=dumb` works!  @haukex - Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It's trying to figure out your terminals size.  You can use a 'dumb' terminal.

```
set TERM=dumb
```

will eliminate the warning.

Comment: Any ideas how to do the same for PowerShell?

Comment: This is a reasonable work around, but it seems like the builders of Win versions of perl (Strawberry in my case) aren't including common sense Windows perl modules that are in cpan to their distributions as a default.